# Output json from sqlplus. Format it so that it appears on one line

Tags: sql, json, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

We are using the below code:

```
SELECT json_object('time' VALUE localtimestamp,'db_schema' VALUE 'USER1', status VALUE COUNT(1) FORMAT JSON) FROM <TABLE> GROUP BY status;
```

However we get the output on 2 lines as below:

```
JSON_OBJECT('TIME'VALUELOCALTIMESTAMP,'DB_SCHEMA'VALUE'USER1',STATUSVALUECOU
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{"time":"2019-10-16T12:14:40.540181","db_schema":"USER1","SUBMITTED":123}
{"time":"2019-10-16T12:14:40.540181","db_chema":"USER1","RUNNING":456}
```

Actually though, we'd like the output formatted on one line like this:

```
{"time":"2019-10-16T11:41:38.393816","db_schema":"USER1", ["submitted":123, "running":456]}
```

So, as you can see we'd like the submitted and running values together on a single line^^

I have tried using the sqlplus concat feature '||' but it doesn't seem to work with json output.

While I continue to work on this, does anyone have any examples of how similar functions may work or any other means by which this goal can be achieved?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want it on a single line, perhaps your intention is to have the result be a single JSON document, in which case something like JSON_ARRAYAGG might be something you ought to look into.

Answer (score 0):

This is as far as I got with this...

```
SELECT json_object('time' VALUE localtimestamp,'db_schema' VALUE 'USER1'),
json_objectagg(STATUS value count(JOB_ID) returning varchar2(32000))
FROM <TABLE> GROUP BY status;
```

^This works, in terms of showing the output on a single line but it's not all in one object as intended. You need the 'returning varchar2(32000)' to avoid characters max'd out errors in versions below 18c.